# How to include util-linux in AOSP?

Tags: android, linux, android-source

How do I include `util-linux` from [here](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/) in AOSP? Where should I add this `util-linux` folder in AOSP so that I can build AOSP and these utils could be added in `/system/bin/` or `/system/xbin/`? And is there any specific `Makefile` or `Android.mk` that I need to make it to compile with Android build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added an application from `util-linux` package in AOSP.

Here's how I did it. I added the `util-linux` (2.34) from https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.34/util-linux-2.34.tar.gz in `external` of AOSP folder.

I just wanted to add `chrt` from `util-linux`. Therefore, I run the normal `make` command in `util-linux` to see what files are compiled for `chrt`. I took a note and created an `Android.mk` accordingly. I am sure there's a better way to do it hierarchically by making the library first and then make the `chrt` executable. However, this works too.

I added the following `Android.mk` at `external\util-linux\`. The Android.mk looks like the following:

```
 LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

 include $(CLEAR_VARS)
 LOCAL_MODULE := sohamchrt

 LOCAL_SRC_FILES := schedutils/chrt.c lib/blkdev.c lib/canonicalize.c \
     lib/crc32.c lib/crc32c.c lib/idcache.c lib/fileutils.c \
     lib/ismounted.c lib/color-names.c lib/mangle.c lib/match.c lib/mbsalign.c \
     lib/mbsedit.c lib/md5.c lib/pager.c lib/parse-date.c lib/pwdutils.c lib/randutils.c \
     lib/setproctitle.c lib/strutils.c lib/timeutils.c lib/ttyutils.c lib/exec_shell.c \
     lib/strv.c lib/sha1.c lib/signames.c lib/linux_version.c lib/loopdev.c \
     lib/plymouth-ctrl.c lib/cpuset.c lib/path.c lib/procutils.c lib/sysfs.c

 LOCAL_CFLAGS = -DHAVE_NANOSLEEP -include config.h \
                -isystem bionic/libc/upstream-openbsd/android/include

 LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include

 include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Now, when I run `m -j8 iso_img`, then Android tries to compile `sohamchrt`. I named the package `sohamchrt` because `chrt` is already provided by `toybox` which have limitations.

The problem is `util-linux` is not fully compatible with `bionic`. So, I needed to make some changes to some .c and .h files such as `fileutils.c, include/c.h`, etc.

After successful compilation, the binary `sohamchrt` appears in `/system/bin` when Android is running, and it works with no issues.

This is also a guide on how you can add a C source file for a userspace executable binary in AOSP.

Comment: `So, I needed to make some changes to some .c and .h files such as fileutils.c, include/c.h, etc.` mind you share with a github repo what changes did you make?

Answer (score 0):

It's always worth checking whether a library you want to add already exists at https://android.googlesource.com/. In your case, unfortunately, it does not.

As `util-linux` does not come with an `Android.bp`. You will have to understand how `util-linux` is built and how [Soong](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/soong/) works to create a custom `Android.bp` for integration. The correct folder to place it would be `external/util-linux/`.

Maybe you will want to take a shortcut and just add `util-linux` as prebuilt binaries. That will reduce the effort.

Please check licensing issues first, though.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I'll check your links and how to make it. Where do you think I should add the folder in AOSP? In `external`?